# What are differences between AutoModelForSequenceClassification vs AutoModel

Tags: nlp, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

We can create a model from AutoModel(TFAutoModel) function:

```
from transformers import AutoModel 
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncase')
```

In other hand, a model is created by AutoModelForSequenceClassification(TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification):

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification('distilbert-base-uncase')
```

As I know, both models use distilbert-base-uncase library to create models.
From name of methods, the second class( **AutoModelForSequenceClassification** ) is created for Sequence Classification.

But what are really differences in 2 classes? And how to use them correctly?

(I searched in huggingface but it is not clear)

Comment: I got a difference : with *AutoModel*, we can use **last_hidden_state** to get the [CLS] token.  *AutoModelSequenceClassification* **last_hidden_state** is not exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between `AutoModel` and `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` model is that `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`  has a classification head on top of the model outputs which can be easily trained with the base model

Comment: So can I use **AutoModel** for *Classification* purpose?

Comment: No actually from the Hugging face course you can see that,For our example, we will need a model with a sequence classification head (to be able to classify the sentences as positive or negative). So, we won’t actually use the AutoModel class, but AutoModelForSequenceClassification:https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/2?fw=pt

Comment: Does that means ```AutoModel``` have frozen weights while ```AutoModelForSequenceClassification``` have trainable weights? Actually, I have a requirement where I only want the model to act as a extractor and not as a trainable model.

Comment: @subho What is classification head?

Comment: @subho: what is the classification head? Is it a linear layer with D_in=number_of_classes? Any online pouter will be very useful!

Comment: It would depend on the architecture, this is the head used for RoBERTa for example - https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/6112b1c6442aaf7affd2b0676a1cd4eee30c45cf/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L1424

Answer (score 6):

To add more information,

both are classes that instantiate any model from a checkpoint; the difference is what you want it to be returned like features or logits to be processed further.

*Automodel* class:

Returns hidden_states/features i.e., contextual understanding of the input sentences by the model.

*AutoModelForSequenceClassification* (consider sequence classification task) class:

The output of Automodel is an input to the classifier head (usually one or few linear layers) which outputs logit/s for input sequence/s. The Softmax of logit is interpreted as a probability. The illustration of an entire pipeline as shown below:

[image: Illustration of an entire pipeline]

*The different tasks could have been performed with the same architecture, but each of these tasks will have a different head associated with it* (as mentioned on hugging face)

- model + sequence classification head --> AutoModelForSequenceClassification
- model + question answering head --> AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
- model + token classification head --> AutoModelForTokenClassification

we can customize these heads according to our case study (e.g., adding dropout/dense layers or modifying the last layer from 5 to 2 nodes, or converting the question_answering head to the text_classification head) on top of the model.

A nice blog on [customizing head](https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-custom-layers-on-top-of-a-hugging-face-model-f1ccdfc257bd).

Source: HuggingFace