# AutoModel for AutoModelTokenClassification Using Hugging Face library

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

according to the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907682/what-are-differences-between-automodelforsequenceclassification-vs-automodel) post, AutoModelForSequenceClassification has a classification head on the top of the model outputs which can be easily trained with the base model (I'm assuming the person talks about AutoModel). I want to use only AutoModel (model similar to AutoModel, as this is the model pretrained by me) for my NER task, but the ner task requires an AutoModelForTokenClassification instead as shown in the following pipeline :

```
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("skimai/spanberta-base-cased-ner-conll02")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("skimai/spanberta-base-cased-ner-conll02")

ner_model = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

The code is taken from [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ezuE7wC7Fa21Wu3fvzRffx2m14CAySS1#scrollTo=s7z9SwmTJtOW) notebook.

Is it possible to use AutoModel (model similar to AutoModel) for NER task?

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to work a little bit more, not just use the pipeline

Comment: do you have some idea of how to use it? i am getting lost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669365/huggingface-bert-tokenizer-add-new-token
:D

Comment: let me go through it, thanks!!